# convert from CSIdentity to a C-compatible string

Tags: c, objective-c

### Intro

I have an objective-C file (.m) in which I'm trying to query local users (through `CSGetLocalIdentityAuthority` and then print each user via `printf` (intentionally using C).

### What do I expect?

get local users with objective c, print them with C pritnf.

Here's my attempt:

### main.m

```
int main(){
    // Query Local Identity Authority
    CSIdentityAuthorityRef defaultAuthority = CSGetLocalIdentityAuthority();
    CSIdentityClass identityClass = kCSIdentityClassUser;
    CSIdentityQueryRef query = CSIdentityQueryCreate(NULL, identityClass, defaultAuthority);
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    CSIdentityQueryExecute(query, 0, &error);

    // get query results
    CFArrayRef users_queried = CSIdentityQueryCopyResults(query);

    //iterate over users
    // Create a users array
    NSMutableArray * users_list = [NSMutableArray array];
    // // number of users
    int users_queried_count = CFArrayGetCount(users_queried);
    
    // // iterate users and save to users array
    for (int i = 0; i < users_queried_count; ++i) {
        CSIdentityRef identity = (CSIdentityRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(users_queried, i);
        CBIdentity * identityObject = [CBIdentity identityWithCSIdentity:identity];
        [users_list addObject:identityObject];
    }

    for (NSString *user in users_list) {
        // NSLog(@"%@", user);
        const char *c_user = [user UTF8String];
        printf("%s", c_user);
    }

    // release
    CFRelease(users_queried);
    CFRelease(query);

    return 0;
}
```

However, this yeilds the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CBUserIdentity UTF8String]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fac024161f0'

You can see I'm trying to convert the `NSString` to a `UTF8` String and print it, but it fails (however, `NSLogging`' it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CBIdentity` is not a `NSString` - its a `CBIdentity`!

If you print it using `NSLog` it gets converted to a string (through `description`), but if you message it with `UTF8String` as you do it does not work.

You've commented out `NSLog(@"%@", user);`

If that actually gives you what you want then change the add part to

```
[users_list addObject:[identityObject description]];
```

Otherwise, note that you are looping `CBIdentity` and not `NSString` so change the loop e.g. like so or similar.

```
for ( CBIdentity * user in users_list ) {
        const char *c_user = [[user posixName] UTF8String];
        printf("%s", c_user);
}
```

Comment: `CSIdentity` is an undeclared identifier, but `CBIdentity` works! thank you!

Comment: Apologies - yes!!!!! CBIdentity ... I fixed the answer

Answer (score 0):

[There is a -fullName property for the class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/collaboration/cbidentity/1423863-fullname?language=objc)

Comment: Could you please ellaborate?